# scrpage2: footer on chapter-starting pages

Tags: header-footer, chapters, koma-script, scrpage2

I am using `scrpage2` and have defined the header and footer.

Is it possible to display the footer also on pages where the chapter begins?
I guess this has to work.
Header is not necessary on those pages (assuming this would look ugly and who needs header on chapter beginning?)

But I don't know what I have to define to have a footer on chapter beginning pages.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `scrpage2` commands for placing elements in the header and footer (`\chead`, `\ifoot`, ...)  feature an optional argument that affects the `scrplain` page style, which is the default style for chapter-starting pages.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\chead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ifoot[A remark]{A remark}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\section{foobar}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```